# How to update webform on checkbox select option when button is click in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio, webforms

I want to update and delete from data based on check box checked. After putting the data in the form, if I checked edit check box then it should go to new page where I should update particular data. And, if I checked delete check box then it should delete that particular data from database.

I'm using asp.net. Please guide me.

Comment: You need to start off with `AutoPostBack` property and **CheckedChanged** event for the Checkbox

Comment: Hey, just out of curiosity, if you are immediately redirecting to another page when checking it, why not use a Button or LinkButton control?